# How To Connect To A Device Over IP Adress In Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am a high school student interested in theatre as well as programming. I am attempting to make an app for our theatre iPad to connect to our lighting console. The iPad has an app that does what we want it to but only the bare minimum. I am trying to make a faceplate panel in the app. I am somewhat familiar with objective-c but I am not sure how to connect and control the console over an ip address like the app from the console manufactures does. How would I go about doing this? Example Code? Tutorials?

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: Who makes the lighting console/system? I know one guy who works on these at one of the common manufacturers, vari-lite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this will be a bigger answer and more of a general rule of thumb guide rather a concrete solution.

To connect to a device over IP, is the same as connecting to it via internet, but to do that it has to be discoverable, and have ports open. If you can find both of those things, you better hope it has an API! If the device has no API, you are shit out of luck unless you want to hack it (which you probably cannot do, thats how security works at the level you are tinkering at).

So, if there is an API, you consume it.

Here are some links about APIs/ REST

http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/whatisrest.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/A/API.html

If it does have an API, just use it with the required get/post/put/patch/delete etc HTTP calls.

So, back to if it does not have one.

If it does not have one, and you somehow manage to SSH or telnet into it (you need the IP, the port, a user and password (if you have a linux/unix/mac (mac is unix) you can try nmap to find the IP and Port on your local network, if it is even there. http://nmap.org/)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet

If you somehow manage to get in, it is up to you to write the API that the device will consume. Bare in mind that it is very possible that even if you get this far, the lighting console could just be a packaged binary that you cannot alter anyway.